# Функции VS лямбды присваиваемые переменным

Tags: javascript, функции, лямбда-выражение

**UPD:**

Раз настоящим всезнающим программистам не нравятся вопросы где интересуются особенностями, то тупо буду задавать вопрос в лоб:

В чём разница и преимущество первого варианта над вторым?

Вар. 1:

```
const findBadWords = (el, dictionary) => {
  let contents = Array.from(el.contents()); // находим всех детей элемента, в том числе и текстовых

    // .. Далее какой-то код
}
```

Вар. 2:

```
function findBadWords(el, dictionary)
{
  let contents = Array.from(el.contents()); // находим всех детей элемента, в том числе и текстовых

    // .. Далее какой-то код
}
```

Вызываются оба варианта одинаково:

```
findBadWords($("#root"), ["word0", "word1", "word2", "word3"]);
```

PS.
Вопрос не про Стрелочные функции (в них уже более менее разобрался) и их различие с Функциональными выражениями.

Comment: [Выражения стрелочных функций](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) имеют более короткий синтаксис по сравнению с функциональными выражениями и лексически привязаны к значению `this` (но не привязаны к собственному `this, arguments, super`, или `new.target`). Стрелочные функции всегда анонимные.

Comment: @And Я больше спрашивал не в целом про лямбды, а про конкретный случай (2 варианта в вопросе), более коротким синтаксисом не выглядит, вызывается одинаково `findBadWords(el, dictionary)`, в чём разница и преимущество первого варианта над вторым?

Comment: Отвечая на ваш конкретный вопрос, могу сказать, что **принципиальная** разница между первым и вторым вариантом, примерно равна нулю (плюс-минус ноль).

Comment: @Deonis Спасибо, тогда тот вопрос, ради чего всё это затевалось: Если разницы **принцимпиальной** нет, почему чаще юзают лямбды, а не "классические" функции?

Comment: Мне кажется каждый юзает что удобнее. Ну и в отдел льных случаях что короче

Comment: Это я минусовал. Принципиальная разница (если она есть) находится в коде, который не показан, если в этом коде, например, фигурирует `this`.

Comment: Ну и я бы минусанул, потому что ответ на этот вопрос имеется в книгах и учебных материалах. Т.е. достаточно прочитать хотя бы одну книгу\ресурс\статью что бы узнать разницу. Отвечать не имеет смысла особого.

Comment: Во-первых, хотел бы себя поправить - принципиальная разница всё-таки есть. Какой бы там ни был синтаксис, но в первом случае объявление функции `Expression`, а во втором - `Declaration`. А что касается вашего вопроса в комментарии, то есть же такое понятие, как "прогресс" и желание следовать за ним вполне объяснимо. А вообще, привычный до недавнего времени синтаксис никто не отменял, но всё должно использоваться к месту, а не просто потому, что "модно".